# How would you translate this Spanish saying "Sacar un clavo con otro clavo" to English?

Tags: phrases, translation, popular-refrains, foreign-phrases

Fellow English Speakers,

I've been trying to translate this common saying from Spanish to English:

> Sacar un clavo con otro clavo.

However, I cannot find any translation that satisfies my curiosity, I read some of them from websites like this one:

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/un-clavo-saca-otro-clavo.205744/

Some of the suggestions are:

- One nail/poison/devil drives out another.
- The best way to get over one man is to get under another.
- The quickest way to get over one man is to get under another one.

Nevertheless, none of them is a good translation, in my opinion, you might ask why? In Spanish, the meaning of the saying is that is not a good idea to get rid of a problem with a new one. Let's take a real-life example of what I mean.

**1st Example:**

> You're dating a pretty girl, but unfortunately, you broke up in a
> very bad way and then you start dating a new one as soon as possible
> in order to overcome your ex; nevertheless, you
> didn't overcome the previous relationship and you're just damaging the other
> girl because you took a fast and bad decision to start a new relationship when you still had feelings for your ex.

**2nd Example:**

> You hate a job in the cooking field because you're not a good cook and
> you resign from your current job, but instead of searching for a new
> job in a new field, you get a new job as a cook, but as a Japanese one
> and then as a Chinese cook and then as a German cook, in the end, you
> are just trying to drive out a nail with another one, but the situation
> is still the same one because you still hate cooking.

In the Spanish language, we use this saying in these kinds of cases. As you can see our meaning is that is a bad idea trying to overcome a problem with another one or get rid of one with a similar one, we don't use it to say you can overcome your current problem with a greater challenge that helps you "forget it". Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the English for "chiodo scaccia chiodo"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/372377/whats-the-english-for-chiodo-scaccia-chiodo)

Comment: @user240918, unfortunately, I cannot agree since the answers that are proposed there doesn't fit our meaning in Spanish, I have read it and fight fire with fire, for example it can be in some cases I'd say, but it's not close enough since he even said about creating jealousy while it's not even close to my example, you're just trying to forget a situation with another one, you're not fighting the problem, to give you some context, it's not my case that I'm representing, but it gave a faster context.

Comment: This is called *dating on the rebound*. I don't know if there's a proverb that goes with it. The nearest I can think of is ***better the devil you know***.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, we can use it for multiple topics not only about dating, for example, you hate a job and you get a new job in the same field.

Comment: Also, I added a second example @user240918 that is not connected to dating.

Comment: Un clavo saca a otro clavo https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/spanish-english/un-clavo-saca-a-otro-clavo

Comment: @user240918 is the same story, "a new worry helps to take the pain away" or "take your mind off the old one" like "the quickest way to get over one man is to get under another one". Not what we mean as I said before, our meaning is that is a bad idea to get rid of a worry with a new one not that you overcome a worry with a new worry.

Comment: @FANM - I think you are confusing literal meaning with usage. If the expression is generally used negatively, just say..a new worry doesn't help to take the pain away.

Comment: And sorry if I insist, but the usage you mention appears to be just a variant of the more common one: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/un_clavo_saca_otro_clavo which is the same as the duplicate question. See: https://www.clarin.com/entremujeres-mexico/amor-y-sexo/verdad-clavo-saca_0_H1MEfNt_.html

Comment: Not the same but related 'out of the frying pan into the fire' means escaping one problem to go to a much worse one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic because translation is off topic for this site. (You can ask if you can better express a certain phrase, if you bring up specific concerns, but nobody here should be assumed to understand the other language or what is the "best" translation of it.) And explaining what it means leads to something subjective, which is off topic.

Comment: Frame challenge: I am native N American, but live in Chile and Bolivia for the last twenty years. I agree with @user66974 that this is almost duplicate, and understand the Spanish saying the way it is mentioned in the Italian question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The remedy is worse than the disease** seems to fit.

> - Measures to deal with the evils of one kind or another often make the situation worse. For example, calling in the armed forces during a period of public unrest is liable to make the remedy worse than the disease if it is done too hurriedly.
>     [Proverb Hunter](http://proverbhunter.com/proverb/the-remedy-may-be-worse-than-the-disease/)

EDIT - [**"six of one, half a dozen of the other"**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/six-of-one-and-half-a-dozen-of-the-other) seems like a good fit too.

"... you start dating a new one" but you soon realize you've just substituted half a dozen for six.

Comment: "Six of one, half a dozen of the other" just means one choice is as good as another.

Comment: @Robusto  [used for saying that two things are equally good or bad](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/six-of-one-and-half-a-dozen-of-the-other)

Comment: That's what I said.

Answer (score 1):

For "un clavo saca a otro clavo"

I would like to suggest: "Out with the old, in with the new".

Comment: That doesn't come close to what the OP is looking for. Have you read the question completely?